# MVC4 Web API - is it possible to add routes from within the individual controller for non-standard & custom actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC web api that for the most part uses the standard route of:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This resides in the `WebApiConfig.cs` routing file.

Certain actions on certain controllers however may want additional parameters added on their routes.

For example a `ContentController` may want an additional parameter passed in to the call like:

```
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{Foo}/{action}/{Bar}/{id}"
```

or any number of other configurations.

Ideally if I'm doing this sort of stuff, I'd like to be able to be able to have those controller specific routes spelled out in the controller itself rather than cluttering up the `WebApiConfig.cs` file.

Is this possible? How is it done? It is a bad idea?

Comment: You probably want to use attribute based routing. See here http://attributerouting.net.

Answer (score 0):

If Mark Jones had made this an answer instead of a comment I'd be able to give him the stack points. But I can't, but this question should be closed as solved. The answer is

> You probably want to use attribute based routing. See here
>   attributerouting.net.

http://attributerouting.net